# Why does instanceof return false for a singleton using a constructor with arguments?

Tags: javascript, constructor, singleton, instanceof

I'm trying to check for a specific type of object in my code.  Even though the object has the constructor in its prototype, it is still failing to return the correct object type and always returns with "object" when using the instanceof operator.

Here's an example of the object:

```
Simple = (function(x, y, z) {
    var _w = 0.0;

    return {
        constructor: Simple,

        x: x || 0.0,
        y: y || 0.0,
        z: z || 0.0,

        Test: function () {
            this.x += 1.0;
            this.y += 1.0;
            this.z += 1.0;

            console.log("Private: " + _w);
            console.log("xyz: [" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", " + this.z + "]");
        }
    }
});
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're returning an object literal with the `constructor` property to set to the function `Simple`. The internal constructor is still set to `Object`, so `instanceof` returns false.
For `instanceof` to return true, you need to set properties using `this.property` in the constructor or use prototypes, and initalize a new object using `new Simple()`.

```
function Simple(x, y, z) {
    var _w = 0.0;

    this.x = x || 0.0;
    this.y = y || 0.0;
    this.z = z || 0.0;

    this.Test = function () {
            this.x += 1.0;
            this.y += 1.0;
            this.z += 1.0;

            console.log("Private: " + _w);
            console.log("xyz: [" + this.x + ", " + this.y + ", " + this.z + "]");
        }
  });
  (new Simple()) instanceof Simple //true
```

Comment: Thanks, I see what's going on now.  I was assuming that the returned object literal was getting assigned as the prototype of Simple.